# In AppCenter Android phone is not cleared between tests

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I have written some **UITests** for my **Xamarin** application using **Xamarin.UITest**. One of the tests clicks on an element and then a pdf viewer is opened. When running this test in **AppCenter** this test succeed but a system popup is opened with **'no available app can execute this action'**. All the tests after this test fails with this error:

> System.Net.WebException : POST Failed  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.HandleHttpError (System.String method, System.Exception exception, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy) [0x0003c] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.SendData (System.String endpoint, System.String method, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, System.Nullable`1[T] timeOut) [0x0013d] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Post (System.String endpoint, System.String arguments, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, System.Nullable`1[T] timeOut) [0x00014] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.HttpApplicationStarter.Execute (System.String intentJson) [0x00035] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.AndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp (System.String appPackageName, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.ApkFile testServerApkFile, System.Int32 testServerPort) [0x000a1] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.AndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.ApkFile appApkFile, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.ApkFile testServerApkFile, System.Int32 testServerPort) [0x00007] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.IExecutor executor) [0x00193] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in :0   at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in :0   at iProvaSearch.UITests.AppInitializer.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Platform platform) [0x00019] in <80fc342154644106b99f6255aba5ae55>:0   at iProvaSearch.UITests.Tests.DocumentListTests.BeforeEachTest () [0x00001] in <80fc342154644106b99f6255aba5ae55>:0   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0

In the screenshot we can see the system popup is still shown. So it seems the app data is cleared correct between tests but the phone isn't. This only occurs on Android, iOS is ok. Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand why it works on iOS but not Android first:

- Opening a PDF in iOS is very simple, as iOS has a PDF viewer inbuilt that doesn't require any installations.
- However for Android, you need to install a 3rd party app (like Adobe PDF reader) to view a file of PDF format.

So in order to make the UITest pass, you can

- Either change the app to convert the PDF into a picture and then open it, requiring some work to be done.
- Or you can use a [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation#conditional-compilation) to only run certain code at the time of a UITest for Android, that will essentially override the test to perform the test function differently.